# Postgres stored proc delete statement not getting executed

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, sql-delete, sql-function

I have a stored proc which looks like this:

```
create function search_contacts
(_name text, _phone text, _email text, _address text, _threshold real)
  returns setof contact 
as $func$ 
declare
  _id uuid := uuid_generate_v4();
begin
  insert into _contact_index_tmp
    select...;
  insert into _contact_index_tmp
    select...;

  return query select c.* from _contact_index_tmp tmp left join 
  contact c
    on tmp.guid = c.contact_guid and tmp.query_id = _id;

  delete from _contact_index_tmp tmp 
  where tmp.query_id = _id;
  return;
end
$func$
language plpgsql;
```

I get the results I want (from the return query statement), but the final delete statement is not getting executed, which I use to clean up my temp table. How can I ensure this is executed?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
return query 

WITH cte AS (
   delete from _contact_index_tmp tmp      -- clear first
   where tmp.query_id = _id
   returning *                             -- return deleted data
)
select c.* 
from cte tmp 
left join contact c
  on tmp.guid = c.contact_guid;
```

Comment: `return query` does not exit a function, the code beneath is reachable.

Comment: @klin... thats what I thought... but then why the delete statement is not getting executed?

Comment: In fact it's executed but doesn't work as expected. I don't know why. Try to reproduce this in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and give us the link.

Answer (score 0):

When you "return" something in a function, it ends that function, so the remaining code will not be executed.
You need to save the data that you want to return in a temporary variable, delete the data, and then return it.

Comment: how do i save it in a variable and access it again? I guess using arrays/ unnest... but am unable to get something working

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING): _RETURN NEXT and RETURN QUERY do not actually return from the function — they simply append zero or more rows to the function's result set_